# Is there a way to display which element in an array failed validation?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm using a Class extends Laravel's FormRequest class. I have arrays incoming, so I have rules like:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'name.*.value' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'email.*.value' => 'required|email',
        ];
    }
```

Basicly when I do my Ajax call it returns 422 with message for eg: 
The name.0.value field is required.

I want it to be something like : The {index}th name is required.

```
public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'email.*.value.required' => 'Recipient email field is required',
            'email.*.value.email' => 'Wrong e-mail format',
        ];
    }
```

Is there an option to include the * somehow in the message? Or am I supposed to process it with JQuery?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use loop like this:

```php
public function messages() {

    $messages = [];

    foreach ($this->get('email') as $key => $val) {
        $messages["email.$key.value.required"] = "email $key is required";
        $messages["email.$key.value.email"] = "email $key is wrong e-mail format";
    }
    return $messages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored the code a little bit, to suit my style. It's working like this as well, if someone like this style more. Of course TsaiKoga's answer is flawless, and good to go with it!

```
public function messages(){

    $messages=[];

    foreach ($this->get('email') as $key => $val) {
        $messages = [
            "email.$key.value.required" => "$key th e-mail is required",
            "email.$key.value.email" => "$key th e-mail is wrong e-mail format",
            "name.$key.value.required" => "$key th name is required"];
    }
    return $messages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->only('name','password','email'), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $messages = $validator->errors()->messages();
        return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'messages' => $messages]);}
```

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator; in your class